# spring-boot service got hang if not used for some time

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am experiencing a problem in spring-boot service. Spring-boot service is getting hang, (not returning anything) until I go to command prompt and hit space/enter or any other key. Anyone else is facing the same issue. Everything is on my local windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not too much details given here . So i will take an educated guess here and respond .
I think you are running your spring-boot application on a windows command-prompt .
Then its not problem with spring-boot application , rather its a behavior of the windows command prompt. If you run any application on a command prompt and select anywhere  on the command prompt as shown in the picture it stop executing there . Its gives a way to analyze some log or prints on console.

If my assumption was wrong please provide more details on your scenario.[image]

Comment: yeah seems like this is the reason. Thanks for the quick response.